# numpy savetxt only saving to 3 significant figures

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code which uses np.savetxt to save arrays which have floats and strings in them. But when i save them they only save to 3 significant figures. When i print `z` it gives my the full floats, so they problem is when i save it. what is causing this? for example `z[0]=(55798.879999999997, 14.08, 'NAN')` but when i read the file it says `557 14. NAN`

```
time=[]
Um=[]
Bm=[]
for j in range(len(h)):
    ee=np.where(h[j]==U[0])
    if len(U[0][ee[0]])!=0:
        time.append(np.mean(U[0][ee[0]].astype(np.float)))
        Um.append(np.mean(U[1][ee[0]].astype(np.float)))
        Bm.append('NAN')
        #print 'U=',U[0][ee[0]],U[1][ee[0]]
    gg=np.where(h[j]==B[0])
    if len(B[0][gg[0]])!=0:
        time.append(np.mean(B[0][gg[0]].astype(np.float)))
        #print 'B=',B[0][gg[0]],B[1][gg[0]]
        Um.append('NAN')
        Bm.append(np.mean(B[1][gg[0]].astype(np.float)))



z=zip(time,U,B)

np.savetxt('file.txt',z,fmt='%.4s')
```

Comment: Please provide the dtype of the numpy variables.

Comment: U.dtype=|S8,  B.dtype=|S10

Comment: I could not get it to work with np.savetxt but have just used file.write instead

Comment: Ok, if that solves the problem, should I look into it. If so, can you please provide sample data for U, B and h.

Comment: Experiment with the `fmt`.  Imagine you are writing `fmt%tuple(z[0,:])` - formatting a row of `z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`savetxt` does a row by row write of your array, using an expression like

```
 f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is derived from your input parameter.  In your example I expect the `fmt` will be something like

```
In [179]: '%.3s %.3s %.3s'%(55798.879999999997, 14.08, 'NAN')
Out[179]: '557 14. NAN'
```

If instead the `fmt` includes proper formats for floats you'll get:

```
In [174]: '%f, %f, %s'%(55798.879999999997, 14.08, 'NAN')
Out[174]: '55798.880000, 14.080000, NAN'

In [175]: np.save('file.txt', z, fmt='%f, %f, %s')
```

read the `savetxt` docs for more information on the formatting.